# Application log files to the systemd journal

Tags: systemd, logs

Something I've been wondering is if it's possible to get systemd to start tailing a log file when a unit is brought up, and to send that data into the system journal.

For the sake of discussion, let's say this program logs to a plain text file, and not to stdout. If I had to give an example, a Minecraft server would work.

I know of `systemd-cat`, but this is just a third party app like `logger` that doesn't tie into the unit system.

Comment: Maybe you can get the program to log to a named pipe and arrange for systemd to `systemd-cat` that named pipe?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this in your service unit file:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c 'tail -f /path/to/log | systemd-cat'
```

It will be somewhat more fragile then the recommended pattern of logging to STDOUT because if the log file is rotated `tail` won't necessarily be connected the file descriptor again until the service restarted.

There is no built-in function to follow a log file that I'm aware. This is something other logging systems like `rsyslog` can do.

Comment: Is it smart enough to kill off the tail when the service is stopped?

Comment: Build a simple hello-world unit file and check!

Comment: tail's -F follows the file by path name instead of my inode id